# Stored procedure that compares Table_1 and Table_2 and updates Table_2 according to data changed in Table_1

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, stored-procedures, stored-functions

Suppose I have two tables Table_1 and Table_2.

Both have identical columns.

`@Table_1`

```
| Id | Col1 | Col2 | Col3 |
| 1  |   a  |   b  |  c   |
| 2  |   d  |   e  |  f   |
```

and

`@Table_2`

```
| Id | Col1 | Col2 | Col3 |
| 1  |   a  |   0  |  0   |
| 3  |   z  |   z  |  y   |
```

How can I write stored procedure that will take rows from `Table_1` compare each column of that row with row in `Table_2` and update the `Table_2` columns accordingly. And if the row in `Table_1` is not found in `Table_2` then simply insert it.

Now. I realize that `INSERT` is easy to write, which will probably look like

```
insert into @Table_2(col1, col2, col3)
select col1, col2, col3 from @Table_1 where id = @id
```

The end result for `Table_2` after the stored procedure is executed have to look like this

`@Table_2`

```
| Id | Col1 | Col2 | Col3 |
| 1  |   a  |   b  |  c   |
| 2  |   d  |   e  |  f   |
| 3  |   z  |   z  |  y   |
```

How about comparing each row and column of `Table_1` with data in `Table_2`?

@Martyn Meeks's Answer works as two seperate statements!

According to https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/3074/use-caution-with-sql-servers-merge-statement/ provided by user @SQL_M using `MERGE` statements is not perfect, but works

@Jayasurya Satheesh's script works too, but uses `MERGE` statement

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're worried about potential issues with the MERGE statement as mentioned, you can do it in two separate statements

```
    UPDATE T2
    SET T2.Col1 = T1.Col1,
        T2.Col2 = T1.Col2,
        T2.Col3 = T1.Col3
    FROM @Table_2 T2
    INNER JOIN @Table_1 T1
    ON T2.Id = T1.Id

    INSERT INTO @Table_2 (Id,Col1,Col2,Col3)
    SELECT T1.Id,T1.Col1,T1.Col2,T1.Col3
    FROM @Table_1 T1
    WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM @Table_2 T2 WHERE T2.Id = T1.Id)
```

EDIT: switched the update and insert statements as Jayasurya suggested.
Otherwise the newly inserted rows are updated as well as being inserted which is unnecessary

Comment: Thanks! Will be avoiding the `MERGE` statements

Comment: I would rather go for the update First and then Do the Insert Because otherwise, you will be updating the Newly inserted records also, which is Just a waste of time

Comment: Yes, very good point. They should definitely be switched round

Comment: @MartynMeeks How should I switch them?

Comment: put the update statement before the insert statement. That way, as Jayasurya says, the update won't operate on the existing rows. I've changed the answer to show what that means

Answer (score 1):

Inserting and updating using a Single Statement Can be achieved using `SQL Merge Join`

Like this Example below :

```
MERGE Table1 T1
    USING Table2 T2
        ON T1.Id = T2.Id
    WHEN MATCHED
        UPDATE SET 
            T1.Col1 = T2.Col1,
            T1.Col2 = T2.Col2,
            T1.Col3 = T2.Col3
    WHEN NOT MATCHED BY TARGET
        INSERT(COL1,COL2,COL3)
        VALUES(T2.COL1,T2.COL2,T2.COL3)
```

Here I'm updating records on Table1 if there are matches Found Based on Id or Otherwise Inserting the Records if No Match

Comment: While that is true, I would not advise it, there are some potential downsides to using merge: https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/3074/use-caution-with-sql-servers-merge-statement/

Comment: This does work. But need to switch places of Table_1 and Table_2 in a script. Thank you!

Comment: @TheOneAndOnlyNoobofCSharp Just two separate statements, one for the insert and one for the updates.

Comment: @SQL_M thanks. Artcile mentions only Sql Server 2008. Are those bugs and "features" applied for a newer Sql servers like SQL 2016?

Answer (score 1):

Create a MERGE Statment.

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[IMPORT_Data]

AS

SET NOCOUNT ON;

MERGE Table1 AS TRGT
USING Table2 AS SRCE
   ON SRCE.Id = TRGT.Id
WHEN MATCHED THEN UPDATE 
        SET TRGT.Col1 = SRCE.Col1,
            TRGT.Col2 = SRCE.Col2,
            TRGT.Col3 = SRCE.Col3,
            TRGT.Col4 = SRCE.Col4
WHEN NOT MATCHED BY TARGET THEN 
            INSERT
            (
                Col1,
                Col2,
                Col3,
                Col4
            )
            VALUES
            (
                SRCE.Col1,
                SRCE.Col2,
                SRCE.Col3,
                SRCE.Col4
            )
WHEN NOT MATCHED BY SOURCE THEN 
          DELETE;
```